# Symfony question. How to use get_partial inside the action.class?

Tags: php, symfony1, partial

When I do this:

```
public function executeGetHTML(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  **$pageContent = get_partial('mypage2'); **
}
```

I get this:

```
Call to undefined function get_partial()
```

so, how to switch it on?  I tried sfLoader::loadHelpers('Partial');  but it says sfLoader is undefined.. :(

Comment: You are not supposed to use helper functions in actions (they are used in templates). I think php's file_get_contents() will do just fine in your case. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `$this->getPartial()` in your actions.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers didn't work for me

I've tried:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
$html = get_partial('partial_name');
```

And it works.

You have to call `get_partial` function in action class without `$this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

And if it still doesn't work. Check if you have:

```
all:
 .settings:
  #....
  standard_helpers:       [Partial]
```

In your config/settings.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the 'partial' helper.Something like this :

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial);
```

And then try:

```
this->get_partial('name of your partial');
```

Note: Provided check the symfony version.If it is 1.4 , it doesn't invoke partial helpers by default.And so we need to the use the code above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider formatting your code with indents for better readability.